# Footer Remover Exchange - remove the unnecessary footer!

Tags: script

### About

I usually scroll to the bottom in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) looking for interesting questions to answer. Hence, it's pretty annoying to see the footer since it doesn't contain any useful content beside the "[Data](https://data.stackexchange.com)" and "[API](https://api.stackexchange.com)" tabs, so no useful content in the footer, so I've decided to remove it.

### Install

You can install the userscript, [minified](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/8c229da4bb40ef4e414677b10bed13a5), or [unminified](https://gist.github.com/lightningmcqueen80/c2fa95115289ab5a243a304ab84067c9).

### Usage

If you don't want to remove the footer on a specific [Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites), you can modify the `x` [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to add any URL of any Stack Exchange site as a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

###### Example

```js
const x = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://stackapps.com"];
```

***The footer won't be removed on Stack Overflow and Stack Apps.***

### Compatibility

The userscript should work across all modern browsers and all userscripts managers.

### Contact

If you meet any problem, it's best to write an answer below with a screenshot of the problem, browser version, userscript manager name, and version for testing purposes.

Feature requests are also welcome, but I tried to make the userscript work for *all* people.

Contributing is also welcome - if you can improve the code, or add some new features.